# Is it a way to check which migration(version) that currently is on a database

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to check which migration version that is the latest that has been running on a database. This to know the state of a certain database.

I read something about entity framework 6 is creating a table to hold track on it. I haven't tried it but I would like to know if theres anything similar to entity framework core.

Comment: dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator.getpendingmigrations(v=vs.113).aspx) might be what you are looking for if I understand you correctly

Comment: Do you want to get the pending migrations in EF 6 or EF Core?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to at least get the

> migrations that are defined in the assembly but haven't been applied
>   to the target database.

( [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator.getpendingmigrations(v=vs.113).aspx) ) via `DbMigrator`s Method `getPendingMigrations()`.

If you want the actual version of a database, there actually is a migration history table `__MigrationHistory` containing a `MigrationId` column which should give you what you want. Here's an article showing how to work with it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx

Comment: I would add some code to show how to fetch the required data, not only give a link on how to work with it.

Comment: Actually, I don't like the "copy & paste"-mentality, so... sorry, not sorry.

Comment: Copy-paste Mentality? What if the link is broken? The answer would be no more valid (copying the important part of the answer is good to garantee the content of the answer). Read this link, then you will like the "copy paste mentality, with mentioning the reference, so it is no more copy-paste mentality" Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: sorry, that's not a valid point for me. it's not the only info I give, it's just that I don't give a perfect copy/paste-solution here, therefore I try to lead the ppl who come here to deal with the topic, not only copy&paste a solution, which actually could be outdated by the time of reading just like the link could be dead by the time of reading.

Comment: that said, sorry for my rude tone in my first comment. I was in a meeting for hours and just let out other things here. :)

Comment: Updated link because stackoverflow is apparently overloaded with pending edits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/history-customization?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to get a list of pending migrations in Entity Framework Core using the following code:

```
var migrationsAssembly = db.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>();
var historyRepository = db.GetService<IHistoryRepository>();

var all = migrationsAssembly.Migrations.Keys;
var applied = historyRepository.GetAppliedMigrations().Select(r => r.MigrationId);
var pending = all.Except(applied);
```

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6110#issuecomment-242220554.

You need to include a couple of using statements:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
```

There is an open issue for a more formal API similar to the one you have in EF 6: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/577